# Get Order details after order success

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, extensions, sales-order

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object

**config.xml**

```
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <abandonedcart_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>abandonedcart/observer</class>
                    <method>saveRedemptionInfo</method>
                </abandonedcart_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events
```

Observer.php

```
public function saveRedemptionInfo(){

    $order_id = $observer->getData('order_ids');
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
```

Same issue happens when I use `sales_order_place_after` and `$order_id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();` . I get error-

> Call to a member function getEvent() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did a mistake in defining the function in the observer. You did not pass `$observer` as an argument to the observer function. 
You can call the function on the event `sales_order_place_after` like below :

```
public function saveRedemptionInfo($observer){

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getData()); 
}
```

Comment: Oops! excuse my poor programing.